# An access to list values in AJAX

Tags: javascript, python, json, ajax

There is a request using AJAX. I'm sending data to the server and getting a response. There are no problems with this. But:

alert(response) returns [object Object].

alert(response.data[0]) returns undefined.

```
function requestFromCalendar() {   
    var first = selected[0];
    var second = selected[1];
    first.month = first.month+1;
    second.month = second.month+1;
    $.ajax({
        data: {
            first: JSON.stringify(first),
            second: JSON.stringify(second)
        },
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: '/get_selected_values'
        }).done(function(response) {
            alert(response);
            alert(response.data[0]);

    })
}

@app.route('/get_selected_values', methods=['POST'])
def get_selected_values():
    values = request.form.get("first")
    first_date = json.loads(values)
    values = request.form.get("second")
    second_date = json.loads(values)

    t = time(0, 0, 0, 0)
    d = date(year=first_date['year'], day=first_date['day'], month=first_date['month'])

    start_date = datetime.combine(d, t)
    start_date = start_date + timedelta(microseconds=123456)

    d = date(year=second_date['year'], day=second_date['day'], month=second_date['month'])

    end_date = datetime.combine(d, t)
    end_date = end_date + timedelta(microseconds=123432)

    data = fetch_selected_date(start_date=start_date, end_date=end_date, login=current_user.get_id())
    if data:
        return jsonify({'data': data})
    return jsonify({'data': []})
```

What's the matter? How to fix?

**EDIT 1**

console.log(response) returns {data: Array(0)}

console.log(response.data[0]) returns undefined

**EDIT 2**

The sending data stores in python code. It is seen in debug mode, so problem is not there for sure

Comment: Using ``alert`` to debug your code can be problematic, because it will cast everything to string. Use ``console.log`` instead, which preserves the type.

Comment: As mentioned by Mike, use "Developer Tools" (F12 in your browser) and `console.log(response);` to see the result of your call. The AJAX call and response will also be visible in the Network tab of said tools. I assume that your `fetch_selected_date()` will return something that is interpreted as an Object rather than an array of Objects.